# replace all <a> tag to some character in php

Tags: php, regex, function, dom, output

I want to replace `<a></a>` to `[]` in php,
as example if I have :

`This is sample test to say you  <a href="nowhere/333" id="blabah" > help</a> and  you can redirect me to <a href="dddd">answer</a>`

I want it replaced to

`This is sample test to say you  [help] and  you can redirect me to [answer]`,

How can I achieve this job in php with regex?

Comment: Strict answer: "no, because PCRE is [finite-state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)"

Comment: use this one : https://eval.in/133065

Answer (score 7):

Use a `Document Object Model` and avoid regular expressions to parse HTML at all costs.

```
echo "[".$dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue."]";
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/133051)

#### The code.. (*for the edited question*)

```
<?php
$html='This is sample test to say you  <a href="nowhere/333" id="blabah" > help</a> and  you can redirect me to <a href="dddd">answer</a>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$srch=array();$rep=array();
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $atag)
{
   $srch[]=trim($atag->nodeValue);
   $rep[]="[".trim($atag->nodeValue)."]";
}

echo str_replace($srch,$rep,strip_tags($html));
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
This is sample test to say you   [help] and  you can redirect me to [answer]
```

Comment: how do we use this ? any link to read or some basic explanation

Comment: no, this is not replace them in there place,  , my text have serveral word and line, I want replace each `<a></a>` tag with `[]`

Comment: @zhilevan, Seems like you edited your whole question ... `-_-`

Comment: NO,I dont edit whole question ,I just add some text to my example to say you my test is not short

Comment: @stealthyninja why you dont write your answer here?

Answer (score 2):

search `<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>`
and replace with `[\1]`

```
<?php
$html='<a href="nowhere/333" id="blabah" > help</a>';
echo preg_replace('/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/', '[\1]', $html);
```

Comment: your code will fail on `'<a href="nowhere><script>alert('evil hacker here')</script> 333" id="blabah" > help</a>';`

Answer (score 1):

Answer should go to Shankar Damodaran, this is his answer extended to meet the OP's requirements:

```
<?php
$html  = 'This is sample test to say you  <a href="nowhere/333" ';
$html .= 'id="blabah" > help</a> and  you can redirect me to <a ';
$html .= 'href="dddd">answer</a> it replaced to';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$elements = count($dom->getElementsByTagName('a'));

for ($i = 0; $i <= $elements; $i++) {
    echo "[" . trim($dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item($i)->nodeValue) . "]";
}
?>
```

<kbd>[Extended Demo](https://eval.in/133067)</kbd>

Comment: +1 mate , but I think he wants to replace the whole thing, so you will be needing the [`replaceChild`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php) of the DOMDocument Class.